# I want to prove the pumping lemma for context-free languages but instead of using Chomsky's form using a new form.

Tags: proof-writing, automata, pumping-lemma

I will be grateful for your help.
The new form is A-> V1.....Vt where t is between 2 and 5.
can you give me a direction for the proof or a proof for this problem?
thank you in advance.